# parital updating table with primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to update part of html table. When i am adding there some components like h panelGroup or ui fragment the table crashes. It display really wirdy things. So atm instead 1 table i made 4 table to achieve situation that there is no panelGroups or ui fragments inside table. Is there any way to make one big table and update part of it ?

```
<table class="simpleTable">
      <tr>
          <td class="label">Select:*</td>
          <td>
               <p:selectOneRadio id="radio"
                        value="#{bean.dateBool}"
                        layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="One date" itemValue="#{false}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Interval date" itemValue="#{true}"/>e
                    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="datesFragment"/>
               </p:selectOneRadio>
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>

<h:panelGroup id="datesFragment">
     <ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.dateBool == true}">
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <p:inputText value="#{beanValue.date1}" label="date from"/>
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <p:inputText value="#{beanValue.date2}" label="date to"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </ui:fragment>

     <ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.dateBool == false}">
         <table class="simpleTable">
             <tr>
                 </td>
                      <p:inputText value="#{beanValue.date1}" label="date"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
<table class="simpleTable">
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: You can use p:panelGrid to align your components and update them by id (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml, http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml)

Comment: Problem is that i use already tables in many places(with special styles etc.) it would be very time consuming to change it all.

Answer (score -1):

hy,

if you use primefaces or jsf i conseil to use tag for jsf or primefaces, example you have use `<h:panelGroup>` and in this tag you have use `<table>`. why you dont change  with `<p:panelGrid>` and remember in the tag panelGrid you can do all: example css style for table for rows for column and ajax event.

when use tag jsf or primefaces you can use attribute update (this attribut you can find it in many tag.

finally when you use tag for jsf or primefaces you can update parte for page, table , form ... etc

Comment: Like i said it would be nice, but anyway it would be too much time consuming. Is there really no solution for updating part of html table in jsf?

Comment: you can do it, for only tag you like update it add attribute id and update it when you like